# How to ask on a registration page if user is private or business

Tags: registration, checkboxes, multi-selection, target-users, business

I have both business users and private individuals registering for my service. I would like to start targeting them differently so in the registration process I want to add a question (under email, name and password):

Will you be using the app for:

- Business
- Private

I thought of making the * into a checkbox (since people may use the service for both personal and business).

Does this seem like the best approach?

Comment: If you're going to ask, make it one or the other. Ask if they'll be **mainly** using the app for business or private. Otherwise you can't really personalize based on use type.

Comment: Does the choice for personal/business affect pricing and/or features in any way?

Comment: No. The question is simply to tailor the experience

Answer (score 1):

If you want an unambiguous answer, use radio buttons.
You probably might want to explain the difference, as people might wonder if there's an advantage to choosing one over the other.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIbBlW.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**A question about naming**

On a related note, what is 'Private' vs. Business?
The word **Private** is about exposing data.

Are you unlocking certain features, but keeping the public facing data about the user the same? In that case, **Personal** is often used for a less robust version of the app.

Comment: I think my use of "Private" is incorrect as you point out. Personal is much clearer.